# Understanding Output layer of a Neural Network in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, nntool

I am experimenting with Matlab, set up a Narx Neural Network with the input vector consisting of 2 values, each of them is delayed 30 times, than I have a hidden sigmoid layer with 40 neurons, another one with 15 and the output layer consisting of one value with a purelin function.

I try to transfer the network to the c/c++ lib fann, so I try to understand which layer does what.

```
netc.b{3} = 0.2302
```

and netc.LW{6} gives me a vector with 15 values. When I set the values to zero by

```
netc.LW{6} = zeros(1,15)
```

And feed the network with zeros by

```
out = netc(con2seq([zeros(1,40);zeros(1,40)]))
```

I would expect only the bias to show up at the output, but I get 40 times the value 311.7813. Setting the bias on the output layer to zero I get 40 times 255.5 as output. What do I get wrong?